# Overleaf - Include HTML file

Tags: python, html, latex

I need to hand in an assignment as a Latex document (which I've created using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)). I also need to include the Python source code, which I've created using [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.io). Since exporting the notebook as PDF basically destroys the layout of it, I've exported it to HTML. I am now looking for a way to include the HTML file into my Latex document. Can anyone suggest a smart workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: you could attach the html file with the attachfile package, then the reader of your document could open it independently

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smarter way.

1. Convert your notebook to latex
   `jupyter nbconvert /path/to/mynotebook.ipynb --to latex`
2. Use \include{mynotebook.tex} in your overleaf document

   - [nbconvert documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
   - [include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123226/how-to-include-tex-files)

#### Edit 1

It's seems that overleaf recomands [import](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project) instead of include.